# Xamarin studio "Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I created a new project by selecting the default theme as Appcompat.Light, then when I run the app, I'm getting this error:

```
"Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download dl-ssl.google.com/android/… and extract it to the /Users/username/.local/share/Xamarin/Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable/23.3.0.0/content directory. (XA5209)."
```

I haven't done anything else other than create a new project, Why am i getting this error?

Comment: Remove the component android.support.v7 and and add this nuget: nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat

Comment: @jzeferino sorry, didn't work

Comment: Are you getting the same error?

Comment: when you said that you I added the references Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll and Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat how did you do that? did you just add the nugget or did you manually add .dll? If you can please share code on github.

Comment: I tried both, via nuget and manual add. both didn't work, can't reference v7.toolbar in .axml file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114533/discussion-between-heisenberg-and-jzeferino).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The process of downloading the `Android.Support.V7` or other nuget could take some time.

If in the middle of the process for some reason you quit the *Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio* or your internet goes down the packages being download as .zip will be corrupt.

After you try to open it again you will see that message "`Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download dl-ssl.google.com/android/… and extract it to the /Users/username/.local/share/Xamarin/Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable/23.3.0.0/content directory. (XA5209).`"

**The solution** that I follow most of the times this happens is to delete the root folder of the package where the error come from (`/Users/username/.local/share/Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable`) and all the .zips inside the folder `/Users/username/.local/share/zips`.

Click here for more [Resolving Library Installation Errors](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/)

Comment: I quited Xamarin studio while it showed "Building solution" for too long. It was actually downloading the required components

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me, so here is what I did to make it work. Basically the solution recommended here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors.
I am developing on Windows 10, with Visual Studio 2017 Community. The Packages are located in `..user/AppData/Local/Xamarin/...`.

I got errors for every package I needed, meaning `Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable`, `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`, `Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable` and about 4 more... So I did the following (solution applies to every package), I illustrate it here for the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` and version 23.3.0.0:

1. Create the 23.3.0.0 directory in `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`
2. Create the directories **`embedded`** and `content` (`embedded` is very important)
3. Extract the zip (`m2repository`) in the `content` folder
4. From the `m2repository`, copy the contents of `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\23.3.0` to the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded` directory, rename the file ending in **.aar** (in my case `support-v4-23.3.0.aar`) to `support-v4-23.3.0.aar.zip`, then extracting all the contents in the same folder (`embedded`). **Note that this is package dependent**, meaning for `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` you will have to copy the contents of the `\content\m2repository\com\android\support\design\23.3.0` folder.
5. Now repeat step 1 through 4 for every package that causes VisualStudio to throw an error.