# Errors with xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

i just downloaded Xamarin studio, and updated everything and installed necessary things. but i still get these errors

1. /Users/chucknorris/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld: Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r25.zip and extract it to the /Users/chucknorris/.local/share/Xamarin/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/23.1.1.0/content directory. (XA5209) (HelloWorld)
2. /Users/chucknorris/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld: Error XA5209: Reason: File /Users/chucknorris/.local/share/Xamarin/zips/0B3F1796C97C707339FB13AE8507AF50.zip is not a ZIP archive (XA5209) (HelloWorld)
3. /Users/chucknorris/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld: Error XA5207: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file /Users/chucknorris/.local/share/Xamarin/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/23.1.1.0/content/classes.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (HelloWorld)
4. /Users/chucknorris/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld: Error XA5207: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file /Users/chucknorris/.local/share/Xamarin/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/23.1.1.0/content/libs/internal_impl-23.1.1.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (HelloWorld)
5. /Users/chucknorris/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld: Error XA5206: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory /Users/chucknorris/.local/share/Xamarin/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/23.1.1.0/content/. doesn't exist. (XA5206) (HelloWorld)
6. /Users/chucknorris/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld: Error XA5207: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file /Users/chucknorris/.local/share/Xamarin/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/23.1.1.0/content/classes.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (HelloWorld)

7./Users/chucknorris/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld: Error XA5206: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory /Users/chucknorris/.local/share/Xamarin/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/23.1.1.0/content/. doesn't exist. (XA5206) (HelloWorld)

anyone have any ideas??

Comment: this a duplicate question, please read my answer in this post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787188/xamarin-studio-error-xa5209-unzipping-failed-please-download

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin studio "Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787188/xamarin-studio-error-xa5209-unzipping-failed-please-download)

Comment: @jzeferino tried deleting the root of the problem as per you answer, still getting the error as ive replaced the file too.

Comment: @thaabitv did you delete the "/Users/chucknorris/.local/share/zip" and all the "/Users/chucknorris/.local/share/Xamarin.Android.Support.*" folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build unsuccessful : Error with Android project in Xamarin.Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869051/build-unsuccessful-error-with-android-project-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try deleting the contents of the following folder (or the folder relating to the Xamarin.Android.Support library in question):

`~/.local/share/Xamarin/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/23.1.1.0`

Clean and rebuild.

If that doesn't work try the following:

Download the zip file mentioned in the error - in this case:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r25.zip

Rename the zip file to the hash of the zip - in this case:

0B3F1796C97C707339FB13AE8507AF50.zip

Place the new zip file into the following folder:

`~/.local/share/Xamarin/zips`

Clean and rebuild.

You can read more information and other troubleshooting tips for this and similar errors here:

[Resolving Library Installation Errors](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors)