# Xamarin not installing packages, error XA5209 & XA5207

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a problem with Xamarin in Visual Studio. 
I am working with Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Android. My problem is that that android component of the project do not install themselves. The zip folder is empty and the component folders are empty.

Solutions I tried:

Delete the the *./AppData/Local/Xamarin* (in windows) folder which is supposed to force the IDE to download the appropriate packages (**does not work**)

Downloaded the m2repository_r29, put it in zip folders and give it his hash name (**does not work**)

Install manually each library : download, unzip and put in right folder (**works**, but is super long for each library from this source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors#Manually_Downloading_m2repository)

```
This is a sample of the error message I get:

    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       An error occurred trying to install required android components on Project 'Project.AndroidClient'.
    Project 'Project.AndroidClient' requires the following components installed on your machine: 
    Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable
    JavaLibraryReference: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/animated-vector-drawable/23.3.0/animated-vector-drawable-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
    AndroidResources: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/animated-vector-drawable/23.3.0/animated-vector-drawable-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
    ...

Please double-click here to install it.

Intallation Errors: XA5209 Unzipping failed. Please download 'https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip:m2repository/com/android/support/animated-vector-drawable/23.3.0/animated-vector-drawable-23.3.0.aar' and extract it to the 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded' directory
XA5209 Reason: ...
```

Please help, I am new to all this and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin studio "Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787188/xamarin-studio-error-xa5209-unzipping-failed-please-download)

Answer (score 0):

Use nugets instead, xamarin is migrating fully from components to nugets on May, 5th