# Android package error for Visual studio 2017 V15.6.6

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I faced this error after updating my Visual Studio 2017.

> An error occurred trying to install required android components on
>   Project 'homebudget'.Project 'homebudget' requires the following
>   components installed on your machine:
>
> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.1.zip--19.1.0Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.AdsJavaLibraryReference:
>
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r19.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/7.5.0/play-services-ads-7.5.0.aar-25.0.0AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r19.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/7.5.0/play-services-ads-7.5.0.aar-25.0.0Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.BaseJavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r19.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/7.5.0/play-services-base-7.5.0.aar-25.0.0AndroidResources:
>
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r19.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/7.5.0/play-services-base-7.5.0.aar-25.0.0Please
>   double-click here to install it.Intallation Errors: XA5209 Unzipping
>   failed. Please download
>   'https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.1.zip' and
>   extract it to the
>   'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\19.1.0\content'
>   directoryXA5209 Reason: Could not find a part of the path
>
> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\19.1.0\content\support\'.XA5207
>   Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK
>   installer. Java library file
>
> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\19.1.0\content\support/v4/android-support-v4.jar'
>   doesn't exist.XA5207 Please install package: 'GPS Ads' available in
>   SDK installer. Java library file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\classes.jar' doesn't
>   exist.XA5207 Please install package: 'GPS Base' available in SDK
>   installer. Java library file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\classes.jar' doesn't exist.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Did you actually follow what the messages tells you to do ? Downloading the file, extracting it ?

Comment: Yes.....but I am unable to download this file :-Please download 'https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r19.zip:m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/7.5.0/play-services-ads-7.5.0.aar' and extract it to the 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices

Answer (score 0):

You could try to follow this link: [Resolving Library Installation Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors). Delete the root folder of the package where the error comes from. In your case it is `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\19.1.0\`.
and delete the zip file in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips`.

You could refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787188/xamarin-studio-error-xa5209-unzipping-failed-please-download) for more information.